Parsing CSV imported Dates
I have a number of csv serialised datetimes. e.g. "04/09/2024 00:00:00"
I can produce these in a table as strings but I wanted to parse and format these in LaTeX.  I've seen variations on /date{} being used but this seems to be producing a document variable not an on the fly.  Could this be done with simplecsv or is it better to do in the rendering section.  At it's most simple as a parsing issue I guess the following is a good start.
https://www.overleaf.com/project/676054e9028e3921cac329c3
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\date{04/09/2024 00:00:00}
\date{04/10/2024 00:00:00}

\end{document}


Depending on how you want to formate the dates, maybe have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2

I did import that package and can see how I could format with it but how do I parse the string to a date?

This will depend on how you import the csv data. Unfortunately, your example does not show this.

welcome! while you could do this with tex, if you have the data in .csv form, it will be more efficient to pre-process it, since you then only transform the data once. if you do it in your document, you have to do it on every compilation. and, of course, you are using a piece of software not designed for this, which adds its own inefficiencies. In contrast, if you pre-process into a form readily digestible by tex, you can use whatever your favourite text-processing/data-crunching tools happen to be. (sed would be my first choice, but that's just me.)
